# Python ldap3 how to get all attributes plus sAMAccountName

Tags: python, ldap3

```py
class LDAPAPI(object):
    ....

    def __init__(self, host, user, password, connection_timeout=10):
        """Sets up a connection to AD, ready to be queried by any
        methods in the class.
        """
        self.server = ldap3.Server(
            host,
            get_info=ldap3.ALL,
            connect_timeout=connection_timeout  # never let it try longer than 10 seconds
        )
        self.connection = ldap3.Connection(
            self.server,
            user=user,
            password=password,
            authentication=ldap3.NTLM,
            auto_bind=True,
            read_only=True,
            check_names=True,
        )
        self.person_cls = ldap3.ObjectDef(['top', 'user', 'person', 'organizationalPerson'], self.connection)

    def get_all_users(self, query=None):
        """
        :param query: eg. query="(employeeID=1234)"
        :return:
        """
        log.info('Fetching all users...')
        r = ldap3.Reader(self.connection, self.person_cls, self.root_folder, query)
        return r.search_paged(paged_size=50)
```

```py
In [2]: u = next(ldap_api.get_all_users('(employeeID=1733)'))                                                                                              
2020-07-31 15:39:41,620 INFO: Fetching all users...

In [3]: u.displayName                                                                                                                                      
Out[3]: displayName: Test User

In [4]: u.sAMAccountName                                                                                                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LDAPCursorAttributeError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-030045dc26b5> in <module>
----> 1 u.sAMAccountName

~/virtualenvs/ad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ldap3/abstract/entry.py in __getattr__(self, item)
    199                 if log_enabled(ERROR):
    200                     log(ERROR, '%s for <%s>', error_message, self)
--> 201                 raise LDAPCursorAttributeError(error_message)
    202             return self._state.attributes[attr]
    203         error_message = 'attribute name must be a string'

LDAPCursorAttributeError: attribute 'samaccountname' not found
```

tried:

```py
r = ldap3.Reader(self.connection, self.person_cls, self.root_folder, query, attributes=['sAMAccountName'])
```

but got error:

```
LDAPCursorError: Attributes 'sAMAccountName' non in definition
```

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, looks like the ObjectDef does not include sAMAccountName automatically, so after manually adding it, it seems to return the field now:

```py
self.person_cls = ldap3.ObjectDef(['top', 'user', 'person', 'organizationalPerson'], self.connection)
self.person_cls += ldap3.AttrDef('sAMAccountName')
```